# Mathematical notation of convergence in latex

Tags: math-mode

How can I type this notation in latex?
[image]

Comment: With `amsmath` use `f_n \xrightarrow{\mu} f`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!!! But the arrow is a bit short, how can I make it longer?

Comment: Like this for example: `f_n \xrightarrow{\enskip\mu\enskip} f `. Alternatively you could use a `longrightarrow` and `overset`. This way the arrow is always the same length: `f_n \overset{\mu}{\longrightarrow} f`.

Comment: @Benjamin: It is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Or you define your own custom `xrightarrow` with a fixed width: `\newcommand{\myrightarrow}[1]{\xrightarrow{\makebox[2em][c]{$\scriptstyle#1$}}}`. You can use it then like this: `f_n \myrightarrow{\mu} f`

Comment: @Benjamin Can you turn your comments in to an answer. It seems like you've answered the question completely.

Comment: @AlanMunn Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Sigur mentioned in the comments you could use `amsmath`'s `\xrightarrow{•}`.

```
f_n \xrightarrow{\mu} f
```

Unfortunately this leads to a quite short arrow:

[image: simple]

There are multiple options to get a longer arrow. You could just add some space at the left and right. But this still leads to differently long arrows depending on the overset content.

```
f_n \xrightarrow{\enskip\mu\enskip} f
f_n \xrightarrow{\enskip L^p\enskip} f
```

[image: with space]

To prevent this you could use `\overset{•}{•}` combined with a `\longrightarrow`.

```
f_n \overset{\mu}{\longrightarrow} f
f_n \overset{L^p}{\longrightarrow} f
```

[image: overset]

But in this case imho the arrow is still a little bit short. So the best way is probably to define a custom `\xrightarrow` with a fixed width like this. Change the predefined value `2em` to get a shorter or longer arrow.

```
\newcommand{\myrightarrow}[1]{\xrightarrow{\makebox[2em][c]{$\scriptstyle#1$}}}‌
```

Which can then easily be used like this:

```
f_n \myrightarrow{\mu} f
f_n \myrightarrow{L^p} f
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Building on Benjamin's answer, if anyone looking for how to get the text under the arrow, you can use `[\mu]{}` instead of `{\mu}`.

```
f_n \xrightarrow[\mu]{} f
```

[image: Rightarrow 1]

Similarly, if you want the arrows to be longer, you can add some space to either side

```
f_n \xrightarrow[\enskip\mu\enskip]{} f
f_n \xrightarrow[\enskip L^p\enskip]{} f
```

[image: Rightarrow 2]

Lastly, you could also get them the same size by using the `\longrightarrow`

```
f_n \underset{\mu}{\longrightarrow} f
f_n \underset{L^p}{\longrightarrow} f
```

[image: Rightarrow3]